# Zod record with required keys

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm trying to create a dictionary like zod schema for an object that has many keys, defined elsewhere, and they all have the same value type. And all keys are required.

```
const KeysSchema = z.enum(['a', 'b', 'c', /*...*/]) // long key list
const ObjSchema = z.record(KeysSchema, z.number())
```

But the yielded type is:

```
{
    a?: number | undefined;
    b?: number | undefined;
    c?: number | undefined;
}
```

But what I want is:

```
{
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
}
```

I want: `Record<'a', 'b', 'c', number>`

but it's giving me: `Partial<Record<"a" | "b" | "c", number>>`

And I can't call `z.record(...).required()` because that's not a thing for zod records.

How can I make a record type with required keys?

[See Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgFBkDGEAdgM7wDSApgJ50DKlAFsyAIZwAvCgB0zGgFcQACgDa+fvgA0BAEYqClTQHoAVKMN6dAXQCUcHTrgAbWgHM4Aaza3gDKrQZwA8moBWXLwCwmJQzNRQxDIs7EF8-KrIolIgasxQMmZmFDCsYMy+AaHJwDSYGQA8eQUQmEWBPAkAfGTEETb84XDU9PAQAQBcDRQD-qL8ojAQAGLAAB7M0RZWcBk4UKrM8wWUMEtwNBBrUBtkQA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to solve it with a `.refine()`

```
  .refine((obj): obj is Required<typeof obj> =>
    KeysSchema.options.every((key) => obj[key] != null),
  )
```

It checks every key in the `KeysSchema` and asserts that all keys are present, and it's not a partial at all.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgFBkDGEAdgM7wDSApgJ50DKlAFsyAIZwAvCgB0zGgFcQACgDa+fvgA0BAEYqClTQHoAVKMN6dAXQCUcHTrgAbWgHM4Aaza3gDKrQZwA8moBWXLwCwmRwYlDM1FDEMizsQXz8qsiiUiBqzFAyZmZhcKKRmMA0zDIyEAFmAFxwlf5w7nAASswAjpLAkcQAPDCsYMwQmHUBAHzCY-nh8Zw8SaIQYDDAXuIAblms5S6sFkIT9XK7JnAAhCJSNjZmyvl5ZP2DvgHCYiWYWX0DQyN+gfMBFNiFEbPxInBqPR4PVav8KPVRPxRDAIAAxYAAD2YsQsViwJWYZCAA)