# How to represent a partial record in zod?

Tags: typescript, zod

I need to represent a `Partial<Record<SomeEnum, boolean>>` with zod.

In TypeScript, we can do this easily:

```js
type SomeEnum = 'one' | 'two'
type MyRecord = Record<SomeNum, boolean>
type MyRecordPartial = Partial<MyRecord>
```

With zod, we can represent the enum and record, but not the partial record?

```js
const SomeEnum = z.enum(['one', 'two'])
const MyRecord = z.record(SomeEnum, z.boolean());
const MyRecordPartial = MyRecord.partial() // This is not a method for Records.
```

What's the idoimatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zod records are partial by default:

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const SomeEnum = z.enum(['one', 'two'])

const MyRecord = z.record(SomeEnum, z.boolean());

type MyRecordType = z.infer<typeof MyRecord>
// {
//    one?: boolean | undefined;
//    two?: boolean | undefined;
// }

const testA: MyRecordType = { one: true } // fine
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgFBkDGEAdgM7wDKuApgKI0CueAvCgHQsuIABQBtfLRb4ANARgB3CPgC6ASiq0GcALIBPAEotqUYnD7J+UY9GIjmIdsLmWARhAgAbFgEMaItTUAbjIYPTAWXUMbUwAVcMiLfmAaTBYoAB4wiIhMKKMTYgA+MgB6UrhKgD0AfjIgA)

You actually have to do extra work to make all the keys required. See [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958464/zod-record-with-required-keys) I asked a while back about how to do that.